# Processing elements in each line into multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need help with processing a file, which contains multiple lines with comma separated elements. The file looks as shown below:

File-1.txt

```
54, 75, 19, 123, 74, 15, 10, 117 
54, 75, 19, 45, 74, 15, 10, 117 
54, 29, 19, 123, 74, 15, 10, 117 
54, 29, 19, 45, 74, 15, 10, 117
```

I want to convert the comma seperated values of each line into two columns separated by tab, as shown below:

Output_File:

```
54  75
75  19
19  123
123 74
74  15
15  10
10  117
```

Likewise, each row saved into a separated file named with the first and last numbers of the original row followed by the line number as shown below

Output_file 1

ABC-54_117-1

```
54  75
75  19
19  123
123 74
74  15
15  10
10  117
```

Output_file 2

ABC-54_117-2

```
54  75
75  19
19  45
45  74
74  15
15  10
10  117
```

and so on for other two rows also. Here in this case it is 4 rows in a file, but I have few files with many rows, which needs to be processed in the same way. I tried scripts with awk, sed but couldn't crack it at all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is `117` from first row missing in your first column? and `54` from second row missing in the second column

Comment: It is not missing, I want the values arranged in that way. To be more clear, I want the elements of the line as follows:  A B, B C, C D, D E into different rows

Comment: Post your attempts as part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F', +' '{f=$1"_"$NF"_"NR; for (i=1; i<NF; i++){print $i,$(i+1)>f}}' OFS='\t' file
```

Output:

```
$ ls
54_117_1  54_117_2  54_117_3  54_117_4

$ cat 54_117_2
54  75
75  19
19  45
45  74
74  15
15  10
10  117
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This script has generated the output as required.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution would be:

```
awk -F, '{ cnt++;for (i=1;i<=7;i++) { system("echo \""$i" "$(i+1)"\" >> \"ABC-"$1"_"gensub(" ","","g",$8)"_"cnt"\"") } }' File-1.txt
```

We have first increment cnt for each record in File-1.txt. We know that there are 8 comma delimited fields in each line so we use a for loop with 8 iterations and inside the loop use the system command to echo the pairs of variables out to a file constructed with the cnt variable and the 8th delimited field. The function gensub is used to remove any spaces in the 8th field.